# Spark - How to do summary statistics on SchemaRDD?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to calculate **the summary statistics on the log count per user**, the RDD I used is from:

```
val fileRdd = sc.textFile("s3n://<bucket>/project/20141215/log_type1/log_type1.*.gz")
val jsonRdd = sqlContext.jsonRDD(fileRdd)

rdd.registerTempTable("log_type1")
val result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS the_count FROM log_type1 GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY the_count DESC")
```

**How can I apply the statistics functionalities provided by Spark MLlib on `result`?** Since the log count of each user is important, I would like to have summary of the following form:

```
Mean: 3.245 (user-id-abcdef)
Min: 1 (user-id-mmmnnnkkk)
Median: 15 (user-id-xyzrpg)
Max: 950 (user-id-123456789)
```

How can I can this? It looks like there's no something like `MapRDD` in Spark's API.